# Ajax form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

i'm making a function that makes every form in my site to submit but "from behind", so the website is not redirected.

This is the code:

```
$('form').each(function(data){
    var el = $(this);
    $(el).submit(function(){
        var action = el.attr('action');
        $.post(action, function(){
            console.log(action);
        });
        return false;    
    });
});
```

The "console.log" log without problems de URL, and the same URL have the data of the form. But the $.post function doesn't submit it.

Any Ideas?, this is in symfony2.

Comment: You really don't need the each statement.. and can just do `$('form').submit(function(){})`

Comment: Can you also post one of your forms?  your jquery works for me (even with the uncessessary .each).  Makes me think there is a problem elsewhere on the page

Comment: Have you added POST to your routing? For YAML you would use something like `requirements: { _method: POST }`

Comment: You can send it nevertheless, there must be something wrong with his form or controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont't forget to post your form data

i havr put an example with $.ajax

```
$(".yourform").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var action = $(this).attr('action');

  $.ajax({
       url: action,
       type: "POST",
       data: data,
       success: function(result) {                        
         //logic here
       }); 
   });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forget to pass the form data, now works like a charm!

Comment: Also, if you are replacing the submitted form element (for example with an updated form in the response), you might want to use `$(document).on("submit", ".yourform", function(e) { /* ... */ })` if you want the same handler on the new form.

Comment: great, if you don't need any further information, you can mark your question as answered. thx !